# Facebook Graph Search API: type=post, can you limit by location?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I'm wondering if there is any way to have a Graph Search call of type=post restrict results to a geographic location like you can when you're searching for a location for example?

I tested it using the same parameters you can use to limit a place search (center and distance) and it didn't work. I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a trick here?

I know that posts don't necessarily contain geo data which is most likely why it isn't enabled.

any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking for exact same thing.. haven't found a workable solution yet.

Comment: Quick update: Specific to post search, I was never able to find a solution to do exactly what I wanted which search for posts in a specific area. About the closest solution I've found which is repeatable (data is available in every post), is running the post search with only the search term as a parameter and then using locale data from the results to iterate through and get rid of non-relevant locales. Unfortunately, this is still pretty broad (countries, languages, etc) but it's all I've found.

Answer (score 2):

From facebook Graph Api docs docs

- When retrieving Posts via the */home, /feed, or /posts* connection, you
  can restrict the results to only those with a location attached by
  adding with=location to the URL parameters: */me/home?with=location*
- Checkins: */search?type=checkin* (This request returns you or your friend's latest checkins, or checkins
  where you or your friends have been tagged; currently, it does not
  accept a q= parameter.)
- Objects with location. The following will
  return information about objects that have location information
  attached. In addition, the returned objects will be those in which
  you or your friend have been tagged, or those objects that were
  created by you or your friends. There are important behavioral
  differences in the results depending on the permissions your app has
  acquired. Please see the documentation for the location_post FQL
  table for more information.
- To search for objects near a geographical
  location, use type=location and add the center and
  distanceparameters: */search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000*
- To search for objects at a particular place, use type=location and
  specify the ID of the place. For example for Posts at Facebook HQ,
  use: */search?type=location&place=166793820034304*

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "locale" param (*...&locale=pt-br*) or setting "Accept-language" on your http header.